# Can't disable power management in Kubuntu 15.04 Desktop

Tags: kubuntu, 15.04, power-management, lock-screen

I'm having trouble with my Kubuntu 15.04 (Plasma 5) installation. I'm running it on my desktop, so I don't have a battery, only AC.

The problem is, that Kubuntu locks the screen after about 15 minutes if I'm idle (that includes watching netflix, etc.) so every time I watch something I get my login screen after 15 minutes, unless I disable Power Management in the lower right corner menu (**Status and Notifications > Battery & Brightness**).

[image: Image: Disable Power Management]

But I can't change this setting permanently and I have to uncheck it after every reboot.

I tried setting the power management profile so that I can easily watch movies, but that didn't have any effect at all.

[image: Image: Power Management Settings]

[image: Image: Power Management Advanced]

I also tried checking the `power_supply` state but all I get is this

```
$ acpi
No support for device type: power_supply
```

I already checked my BIOS settings; it's set to ACPI so that shouldn't be the problem.

Any idea what I could do to solve this problem?

Answer (score 3):

Go to **SystemSettings → Workplace → Desktop Behavior → Screen Locking** and uncheck **Lock screen automatically after**. Test this.

Auto screen locking should disappear.

But screen can be auto turned off because of **SystemSettings → Hardware → Power Management → Energy Saving**. I recommend unchecking all timers (**Dim screen**, **Screen energy saving**, **Suspend session**).

After that, close the **System Settings** window, and then open it again and check if these options stay disabled. If they appear to be still active then you have encountered the bug in Plasma 5 that I have now, and the only solution for me is manually remove some lines from the file

```
$HOME/.config/powermanagementprofilesrc
```

or just (make a backup copy under another name and) delete the original... and re-login, and then check the options again...

---

When you watch video with **smplayer**, you can enable "heartbeat" in smplayer to simulate user activity and prevent energy saving actions by plasma.

In the smplayer window go to **Options → Preferences → Advanced → Options for mplayer/mpv → Options** insert this line in the text box:

```
-heartbeat-cmd="qdbus org.freedesktop.ScreenSaver /ScreenSaver org.freedesktop.ScreenSaver.SimulateUserActivity"
```